XmlHttpRequest file (image) <=> raw data reformatting?
I have downloaded some basic image somewhere from google:

this picture looks like:

then I use this httprequest to read and save raw data of the image:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", pInput, false);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
};

and it looks it works fine but its only somehow reformatted:

any idea how to at least find out which format it is returns from XMLHttpRequest so I can try to reformate it back?
NOTE: I use the solution to read raw data of the image to be able to send it via next httprequest to CDN server via their API. I have found out the Image after upload can not be viewed, so I have identified the problem of the first httprequest above that the encoding is different from input file... basicaly when I save this initial httprequest as .jpg file, it can not be displayed as no software know this format

What is the actual issue you're trying to solve? How is the change in encoding relevant?

Most of the output looks the same, but there appear to be some issues related to character encoding. But I can't tell what actual problem you are trying to solve here. What are you trying to do with this data?

when it has this encoding, it can not be displayed as image anymore, I have add a "NOTE" to the quesiton

when I save this initial httprequest as .jpg file there's a lot of steps that you're doing that are not detailed here.  eg it seems that you're loading an image into the browser as text then saving from the browser.  This won't work.   Do not display an image as text and then save it and expect it to be the same image.  Use a binary method (hint, not xhr.responseText) to read and save the image without displaying it.  Alternatively, if you must do this manually, then open the image in the browser as an image and save that.   It won't be the same image, but it will be an image.

you haven't shown what you are doing to send it via next httprequest - that's where your mistake is most likely - hard to tell without the code

interesting use of synchronous request and onreadystatechange - from the docs "Warning: This should not be used with synchronous requests"

yea somehow quickly (not properly) rewritten from async to sync... however if i fix it to propert way, makes no difference

@JaromandaX the issue is in the script I provided in the quesiton... in input image you can see first character is ˙ (ascii 729), and when i receive responseText i try to debug first character, which is ? (ascii 65533)

First verify that the server at pInput is correctly serving your image by visiting pInput in your browser and make sure you get a visible image back.  You can refer to mdn docs to figure out how to get the binary data correctly via xmlhttprequest.

this was a nightmare, but I guess the issue that ByteScale CDR API didnt like the string as binary input... however byteArray of the image XMLHttpRequest works fine.
Working example:
function share_image(pInput) {
    var xhr_image = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr_image.open("GET", pInput, false);
    xhr_image.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr_image.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr_image.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

            const image_return = xhr_image.response; // Note: NOT xhr_image.responseText
            var xhr_upload = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // when responce received then do the following script:
            xhr_upload.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (xhr_upload.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // && xhr_upload.status >= 200 && xhr_upload.status <= 400 // on Windows this works fine, on Android not?

                    // Check if reply is proper JSON
                    try { var response = JSON.parse(xhr_upload.responseText.toString()); }
                    catch (exception) {
                        console.log("Return message is NOT Json:", xhr_upload.responseText.toString());
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Return ERROR check
                    if (response.error) {
                        console.log("ByteScale API Error: " + JSON.stringify(response.error));
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Show responce here
                    console.log("ByteScale API Reply:", JSON.stringify(response));
                    return true;
                }
            }

            xhr_upload.open("POST", "https://api.bytescale.com/v2/accounts/yyyyyy/uploads/binary");
            xhr_upload.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'image/jpeg');
            xhr_upload.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer public_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
            xhr_upload.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');      // QML does not know XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') ???
            xhr_upload.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', image_return.length);     // only if not sending header Transfer-Encoding: chunked
            //xhr_upload.setRequestHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');  // no idea how this works
            xhr_upload.send(image_return);
        }
    }
    xhr_image.send();
}

